# What to do with stone age x86 computers?

Tags: hardware, x86

Not sure if retro is proper place... I have two old notebooks with x86 processors in the 100s range of MHz. While nostalgics might appreciate them, I'm wondering if there is any proper point in keeping them. The hardware is modern enough such that to the best of my knowledge nothing would exclusively run on them but not on a current PC, whereas using them for modern applications sounds like a horrible idea in terms of energy efficiency. But just disposing of them (properly, of course) also sounds like pity... So what are, objectively, the best options?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use the term /stone age/, as these are considerably more modern than what this SE generally deals with, but I do see the problem. Some people are building high-spec Win9x gaming machines from desktop hardware of that era, but notebooks are indeed a bit of problem, as they usually offer less performance and are not expandable. Unless it's an iconic design (like the Thinkpad 701's butterfly keyboard) or I had a personal connection to a machine (the one I, say, typed my thesis on), I probably wouldn't keep it.

Comment: @MichaelGraf Okay, stone age in terms of x86 computing then  Of course in terms of RC it's Renaissance maybe 

Comment: Your're only digging yourself deeper into that hole ;-) There are some 10+ years of x86 history before we get to the 100s of MHz, and while I would find a mid-80s laptop computer eminently collectible simply because how early they were, this doesn't hold (for me) for a mid-to-late 90s machine.

Comment: Without saying anything more about the age, I'd say it is very important to know exactly which make and model they are. If they are rare things you stand a chance that someone is interested.

Comment: If they can play picture screen savers, load up all your pictures on the hard drive and using it to display pictures.  You'd be surprised about the pictures that you have and every so often, someone will ask you where the picture was taken.  If you take the disk drives apart, the disks make amazing unbreakable mirrors and the magnets are like nothing you've ever used - if they pinch your skin when they snap together, it really hurts.

Comment: Could you be more specific about x86? That covers a wide range. My first laptop was 286 DOS based, but anything up to a pentium running Windows XP might be covered by that description.

Comment: If they have any form of 3D acceleration, then that would be a particularly *useful* window of time, because there are still games that only get along with Windows 9x and don't like Wine, but Windows 9x is too old for there to be guest drivers for things like VirtualBox.

Comment: @MichaelGraf Make that more like 15-20 years, as the 86 was introduced in 1978, while the first Intel to go up to 100 MHz was introduced 1994 and it wasn't until 1997 that it reached 200 to even touch the 100**s** mentioned. So if at all, this is at best a 'late medieval' example, as it's less like half ways between stone age and today, isn't it? Beside that, I would think the question is asking for opinions, does it?

Comment: With 'hundreds' of MHz it's most likely a Pentium or later, so anything that runs on Xp can be used. Or make it a fun machine, install any DOS (FreeDOS) and [DOjS](https://github.com/SuperIlu/DOjS) to write 3D games with GLIDE and 3dfx support in ECMA-Script. Not really retro but quite a lot fun.

Comment: The stone age ended ten years ago.  It has always ended ten years ago.  When I took my first programming course in 1962, the stone age had ended in 1951.

Comment: @WalterMitty Damn, the system doesn't allow me to give more than one upvote for your comment.

Comment: 10 years ago? I don't know. I can remember the 1970s and the 1980s a whole lot better than I can remember the 2000s and the 2010s. Computers from way back when were different from each other and different from the computers of today in all kinds of interesting ways. But in the last 10 years? Uh, lessee... they do better on various performance benchmarks, and they have more memory, and removable media has mostly disappeared, but has anything else changed?

Comment: Do they have parallel printer ports? RS232 Serial ports? PCMCIA?

Comment: @SolomonSlow — It's interesting how the 90s are missing completely from the comment, as if they never existed ;-) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The hardware is modern enough such that to the best of my knowledge nothing would exclusively run on them but not on a current PC

This statement partially answers your question, given that the idea of a "current PC" isn't frozen in time. 10 or 20 years hence, you may find it much more difficult to find a "current PC" that can utilize the old software (or, more importantly, **your data**) that worked perfectly well on that old hardware you decided to recycle 10 years earlier.

> Using them for modern applications sounds like a horrible idea in terms of energy efficiency

A computer, like any tool, always works best when used as it was intended. So you have a very valid point here that old hardware that wasn't designed with the latest version of Windows or some application in mind won't work to the same level as the new hardware that *was designed for the latest OS and applications*.

Conversely (to use an analogy), I still have the same hammer in my toolbox that I bought 30 years ago and I've found that the nails I want to drive haven't really changed.